# Problems with a Trig Method using BlueJ

Tags: java, methods, trigonometry, bluej

I am trying to create a method in BlueJ called,

```
toRadians();
```

The point of this method is to take a any number below 360 and change it into radians. Here is the method code.

```
public void toRadians(double tempDegrees)
{
    Math.toRadians(tempDegrees)
}
```

The line of code used to call this method:

```
toRadians(beamAngleHalf);
```

When this method is called is doesn't change beamAngleHalf into radians. I know this is very basic. How can this be resolved?

Comment: The method can't change the value (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) Instead it returns a new value. So you probably want `beamAngleHalf = toRadians(beamAngleHalf);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that could be explained here, including: the difference between Objects and primitives in Java, and the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value, but the short answer is that `Math.toRadians(tempDegrees)` is not changing the value that is passed into it, it is instead returning the value represented in radians.

You instead need to return what is returned by `Math.toRadians()` in your `toRadians()` method.

```
public double toRadians(double tempDegrees)
{
    return Math.toRadians(tempDegrees);
}
```